# Why does matplotlib.gridspec's tight_layout not work correctly with pyplot.subplot whereas it does with fig.add_subplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create two subplots next to one another using gridspec (the real plot is more complicated but this is the basic idea). I am creating the subplots using `plt.subplot`, but this does not seem to produce the expected result. I get only the second subplot on the right side of the figure, and not the first one.

On the other hand, if I create the subplots by using `fig.add_subplot`, the plot appears correctly although I get a tight_layout warning. I am a little surprised at this behaviour, since pyplot's subplot function internally calls fig.add_subplot (and then does some checking to see if the subplot already exists -- I guess?). Here is the code that produces only the rightmost subplot. Switching the comments to use `plt.gcf().add_subplot` gets it to work as expected.

```
from matplotlib import gridspec,pyplot as plt

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1,1)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0,0])
# ax1 = plt.gcf().add_subplot(gs[0,0])
ax1.plot(range(3),range(3))
gs.tight_layout(plt.gcf(),rect=[0,0,0.45,1])

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1,1)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0,0])
# ax1 = plt.gcf().add_subplot(gs[0,0])
ax1.plot(range(3),range(3))
gs.tight_layout(plt.gcf(),rect=[0.55,0,1,1])

plt.show()
```

Am I doing something wrong, or am I missing something here? For reference, here is what pyplot.subplot primarily does:

```
fig = gcf()
a = fig.add_subplot(*args, **kwargs)
bbox = a.bbox
byebye = []
for other in fig.axes:
    if other==a: continue
    if bbox.fully_overlaps(other.bbox):
        byebye.append(other)
for ax in byebye: delaxes(ax)

return a
```

My question is: why does using pyplot.subplot not produce the same result as fig.add_subplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `subplot` does is checking for overlapping plots and deleting them if they exists. Your second subplot overlaps the first one so your second `plt.subplot` will delete the first one. `Figure.add_subplot` does not delete overlapping subplots.

Note that you are creating subplots that fill the whole figure:

```
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1,1)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0,0])
```

This is a subplot in a 1x1 grid so it will fill the whole figure and overlap any previous subplot.

BTW the issue has nothing to do with `tight_layout` which is working correctly..